# What kind of method is used at this statement? <property .. value = "@ .. @" />

Tags: jpa, credentials, parameterized, persistence.xml

I'm taking the ownership of a Java application which works with JBoss, and I found that the Persistence.xml file have the following statments..

```
      <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="@USER@"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="@PASSWORD@"/>..
```

USER and PASSWORD are declared in properties file, however the values bounded with At signs is not familiar for me. I've not seen this before, what kind of method is being used here?

Comment: At a guess something in the build system is replacing these for you.  In a maven pom.xml, for example, there is the concept of "filters" that can do these replacements for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken this is the maven genapp plugin...

**The filter itself is used copying the files defined by maven.genapp.repackage and maven.genapp.filter and will replace any occurrence of @PARAM@ in the files with the value of maven.genapp.template..**

At least that's where I've seen this kind of constructs before.

Comment: Yup similar to: http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/plugins/genapp/properties.html. Have you seen any example about this?

Comment: @Jrr sorry, I just remember the plugin, it was a while ago :)